# Removing Widgets with defined ObjectName[s] in a for loop

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt6

First of all, here is my *current* code in question:

```
def scpSearched(self):

    scpInfo = SCPScraper(self.scpInput.text())  #   Store SCPScraper dictionary in a variable
                                                #   ↑   scpInfo = {"Heading":"text","Heading2":"text"...}
    self.scpInformation = QWidget() #   Widget to store all SCP Information

    index = 1
    for key in scpInfo:
        objectNameHeading = "Heading {}".format(index)  #   Create ObjectName for Headings
        objectNameText = "Text {}".format(index)  #   Create ObjectName for Text

        if self.scpSearchedBool == True:    #   Default self.scpSearchedBool is False
                                            #   ↑ If True, then the screen is filled with previous text
            self.layout.removeWidget(self.scpHeadingLabel.objectNameHeading)    #   Atempted Removal of previous Headings
            self.scpHeadingLabel = None
            self.layout.removeWidget(self.scpTextLabel.objectNameText)  #   #   Atempted Removal of previous Text
            self.scpTextLabel = None

        self.scpHeadingLabel = QLabel(self.scpInformation)
        self.scpHeadingLabel.setText(key)   #   Set Heading to current key
        self.scpHeadingLabel.setObjectName(objectNameHeading)   #   Create addressable name based on index

        self.scpTextLabel = QLabel(self.scpInformation)
        self.scpTextLabel.setText(scpInfo[key])  #   Set Text to Text at current key of scpInfo
        self.scpTextLabel.setObjectName(objectNameText) #   Create addressable name based on index
        self.scpTextLabel.setWordWrap(True)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.scpHeadingLabel, index, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scpTextLabel, index, 1)

        index += 1

    self.scpSearchedBool = True #   Indicate that the page has contents on it
```

I am creating an application that displays the contents of a dictionary. The amount of contents it has to display cannot be pre-determined as it is scraped from the web, and because of this I generate Qlabels through a for loop. I have made each label have a setObjectName, that is generated depending on a variable, `index`.

However an issue I am noticing is that text gets overlapped, as it is not removed as seen below:

[image: Overlapped Text from searching "002" and "003"]

Logically, I decided to come up with a way to remove each label and then replace it, and I wanted to use the ObjectNames I had assigned them, which is what is seen in the code above. However, I assume that my referencing of the widgets by their ObjectName is incorrect.

However when I used the lines `self.layout.removeWidget(self.scpHeadingLabel)` and `self.layout.removeWidget(self.scpTextLabel)`, only the last element of the text is replaced, with the rest staying the same, which is peculiar as if the code was working, shouldn't it delete the previous text, not keep it?

[image: Initial search of "002"]
[image: Search for "003" after the initial search for "002"]

I am very puzzled and have many questions. How do I address widgets by their ObjectNames, since the way I am doing it is incorrect? How do I remove each QLabel if not by ObjectName? What is going on with the replacement of just the last label?

Comment: Just keep a list of objects as an instance attribute, when the function starts remove each element in the list until it's empty, and add new ones when creating the labels. Also, don't create instance attributes for objects created in a for loop, it doesn't make any sense, since you're constantly overwriting the previous reference and always leaving just the *last* occurrence.

Comment: As can been seen from the docs, [removeWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#removeWidget) takes a reference to a *widget*, not a string. Also, it does not delete the widget - that is the responsibility of the caller. The object-name has no relevance in this context. More generally, it's questionable whether using a list of labels is the right approach here. For static text, it might be better to display the information using an HTML table in a QTextBrowser.

Comment: I'm not sure what @musicamante meant by keeping a list of instance attributes, but the explanation as to why only the last widget was being changed was very helpful.

Comment: I ended up changing the widgets from Labels to a text edit, which made my job infinitely easier. Thank you for the suggestion and making me look into other widgets @ekhumoro!

Comment: @CatRass create an instance attribute in the `__init__` (eg: `self.labels = []`), then at the beginning of `scpSearched()` add: `while self.labels: self.labels.pop().deleteLater()`, and in the loop add all new labels to `self.labels` again.